# Move all object from a lib to another lib

Tags: ibm-midrange

I try to move all the object from a lib to another lib.
I want to use something like "MOVOBJ OBJ(LIBX/*ALL) TOLIB(LIBY)" but this doesn't work. It says that *ALL is incorrect.

I also try "MOV OBJ('/QSYS.LIB/LIBX.LIB/*ALL') TODIR('/QSYS.LIB/LIBY')" that doesn't work too. It says that it cannot find /QSYS.LIB/LIBX.LIB.

I don't find the right command to move all the object.

What is the command I need to use ?

EDIT : I cannot use "DUPOBJ" because there is not enough space to duplicate some big table.

Currently I get the list of object in my library and I move them one by one.

Comment: If you want to **move all** objects, why not simply rename the library to the new name with RNMOBJ? Are multiple libraries being "moved" to a single new library?

Comment: I wan to move the content of the library X into library Y but library Y already contains many objects.

Comment: Are any SQL objects created in the source library? If so, they should not be moved but rather recreated/copied. Also, there are some objects that cannot be "moved" between libraries, so "*ALL" couldn't always succeed if allowed.

Answer (score 2):

When using IFS naming, you need to think Linux/UNIX...

CL type special values such as *ALL are not supported.  Instead use just the * like you would in UNIX

```
MOV OBJ('/qsys.lib/test1.lib/*') TODIR('/qsys.lib/test2.lib/')
```

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.
I try this but it says "Object /QSYS.LIB/MYLIBX.LIB not found".

Comment: Post the actual command you are using.  I tested the above, so it works fine.  On 7.1 anyway.  What release are you using?

Comment: I use release 7.1 too.

Here is the exact command I use :

"MOV OBJ('/QSYS.LIB/AAA_TEST.LIB/*') TODIR('/QSYS.LIB/AAA_TESTS/')". 

When I use "DSPLIB LIB(QSYS)" I see that the lib AAA_TEST exists.

Comment: should be `TODIR('/QSYS.LIB/AAA_TESTS.LIB/`  you are missing the .LIB

Comment: @YLombardi The use of `DSPLIB LIB(QSYS)` wouldn't be best. Much better would be DSPLIB AAA_TEST to see if AAA_TEST exists. Also, does `AAA_TESTS` also exist? Or are you trying to create it with a MOV command?

Comment: Yes both library exists.

Comment: @YLombardi If both libraries exist and you see the error message `"Object /QSYS.LIB/MYLIBX.LIB not found"`, then you are not showing us the **actual commands** that you are using. We can't correct an error without seeing what is actually being done. Copy/paste actual command and actual message text. Also, provide error message ID when posting message text. (Different error conditions might share similar or same text.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're moving ALL the objects in a library ... maybe a SAVOBJ / RSTOBJ / DLTOBJ would be the best bet.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my colleague if this solution can be used in our process.

Comment: Note that if there isn't enough space on the system, a SAVOBJ of the `big table` probably can't be done to *SAVF. A device name would have to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using PDM. `STRPDM`, option 2, enter the name of your from-lib. (Or `WRKOBJPDM from-lib`.)

Then take option 11 against the first object and press F13 to repeat to the end of the list. Press Enter and you'll be prompted for the to-library.

Comment: Hi.
That is the solution that is used today but we try to automate this process with a java application.
I don't think I can use PDM with the java library JT400.

Comment: No. Well, from Java you'd probably want to just treat it as a Unix filesystem and use the "*" wildcard, as described above. Or use the toolbox classes and suitable greenscreen commands. But I guess that's what you were trying. Since you can't use *ALL, I guess you could iterate over all the objects in your Java code, and do a MOVOBJ for each one.